# How do "{}" (braces) create a hash, and why can I store it as a scalar?

Tags: perl, hash

In [perltoot](http://p3rl.org/toot#Object-Representation) is this code:

```
$rec = {
  name  => "Jason",
  age   => 23,
  peers => [ "Norbert", "Rhys", "Phineas"],
};
```

Is this a string or some sort of hash (I thought hashes were declared with `%`)?

Comment: See perldsc and perllol, which should be understood before throwing perltoot into the mix :-) -- it (`{...}`) evaluates to a HASHREF (a scalar).

Comment: Make that [perldsc](http://p3rl.org/dsc), [perllol](http://p3rl.org/lol) - hyperlinks work in comments, too.

Comment: I'd start with [perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's a [reference](http://p3rl.org/perlref) (sort of a pointer) to a hash. And a reference (as anything that begins with '$' in Perl) is an scalar, in this case a scalar that "points" to a non-scalar value.

```
  @ta = (10,20,30); # array
  $tb = [10,20,30]; # reference to an array
  %tc = (name => 'John', age => 23); # hash
  $td = {name => 'John', age => 23}; # reference to a hash

  print( $ta[1] . "\n");
  print( $tb->[1] . "\n");

  print( $tc{'name'} . "\n");
  print( $td->{'name'} . "\n");
```

Understanding references is essential to any more than casual Perl programming. For example, you need to use references to make nested structures ( arrays of arrays, etc).

Answer (score 6):

`{ }` creates both a hash and a reference to it, and it returns the latter.

```
{ a => 1, b => 2 }
```

is roughly equivalent to

```
do { my %anon = ( a => 1, b => 2 ); \%anon }
```

This operator is documented in [perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html).